# Using mailx without storing a password

Tags: command-line, security, email, mailx

I'm trying to setup `mailx` to use my Gmail account. I've found a configuration that can send mail successfully but it requires me to store my email password in a configuration file in my home directory. I would like to be prompted for the password every time rather than storing it.

I've tried leaving out the *smtp-auth-password* field where the password is present but the program does not prompt for a password and instead gives me this error: *User and password are necessary for SMTP authentication.*

Is there any way configure `mailx` such that my email password is used in a secure manner?

Here is my `mailx` config file:

```
account gmail {
    set folder=imap://(removed)@imap.gmail.com
    set smtp-use-starttls
    set ssl-verify=ignore
    set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
    set smtp-auth=login
    set from=(removed)@gmail.com
    set smtp-auth-user=(removed)
    set smtp-auth-password=(removed)
    set nns-config-dir=~/.certs
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of `mailx` are you using?

[heirloom-mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) 12.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 prompts me for the password every time if there's no `smtp-auth-password` setting in `~/.mailrc`.  This feature was added in 12.0 in March 2006 according to [ChangeLog](http://nail.cvs.sourceforge.net/nail/nail/ChangeLog).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with heirloom-mailx 12.5.

Comment: It seems to be working now, must have just been a misconfiguration. However it is unusual that earlier it gave an error message indicating the password field must be supplied.

Comment: @ZeroKelvinKeyboard You can run as `mailx -v` to see debug output including full of SMTP AUTH activities.